# Modelling a store in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, mapping

Imagine a store model where a `store` can have many `items` and each `item` can have different `price` which can differ by `store` (different stores can have the same item but different price).

This is exactly how store is in real life.

So far, I have `item`, `store`, and `price` as a model.

How would I model this association in Rails? Adding/removing models is not a problem.

I would also need this association to easily enables me to do such query:

"Given an item (or an id of an item), return the list of stores that carry this item including their prices".

So far, I have the following associations:

```
Store:
  has_and_belongs_to_many :items
Item: 
  has_and_belongs_to_many :stores
  has_and_belongs_to_many :prices
Price:
  has_and_belongs_to_many :items
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about a fourth model, StorePrices, which would allow a `has_many` `:through` relationship.

```
Item:
  has_many :store_prices
  has_many :stores, :through => :store_prices

Store:
  has_many :store_prices
  has_many :items, :through => :store_prices

StorePrice:
  belongs_to :store
  belongs_to :item
```

The store_prices table would look like this:

```
id -> integer
store_id -> integer
item_id -> integer
price -> decimal
```

And you could get the stores for the given item like this:

```
stores = item.stores
```

The price of the item in the first store:

```
price = item.store_prices.first.price
```

Comment: Why do I need the `has_many :store_prices` in `Item` and `Store` ? What does it accomplish?

Comment: It tells the model that you have a one-to-many relationship with the store_prices model, which "glues" your unique item prices with the store they are found in. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using has_and_belongs_to_many I would use has_many :through

A store retails items

```
Store
has_many :items through :retails
has_many :retails

Retail
belongs_to :store
belongs_to :item

Item
has_many :stores through :retails
has_many :retails
```

Then you could add a price to the retails table which would be per item per store.